# Transpiled Angular 4 files not rendering on web browser

Tags: angular

I have transpiled angular(ver 4) files using cli :

```
ng build --prod
```

Build Logs :

> C:\Users\TableApp>ng build --prod Your global Angular CLI
>   version (7.1.4) is greater than your local version (1.4.10). The local
>   Angular CLI version is used.
>
> To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch
>   false". Date: 2019-02-06T09:32:27.806Z Hash: 8fa5176d847526aca17c
>   Time: 54627ms chunk {0} polyfills.09e0b303988c1d6c3513.bundle.js
>   (polyfills) 104 kB {4} [initial] [rendered] chunk {1}
>   main.e220e3c0fa86b1c6bf08.bundle.js (main) 27 kB {3} [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {2} styles.cc799a8655f46a70d4fa.bundle.css (styles)
>   124 kB {4} [initial] [rendered] chunk {3}
>   vendor.0c33029eb20ce4dbb587.bundle.js (vendor) 1.28 MB [initial]
>   [rendered] chunk {4} inline.eac5b5cb55d53075e1aa.bundle.js (inline)
>   1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]

the following error(s) appears on the web browser console (currently using Chrome) with no contents rendered on screen first time and later respectively.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions for correcting the transpilation?

Comment: not that it will help, but you dont need polyfills for chrome, only edge and ie

Comment: however, i can see that its looking for `.../node_modules/...` in the url, this is your issue as it shouldnt reference the node_modules folder after it is built

Comment: do you have the same issue with `ng build`?

Comment: You are probably serving the wrong files, it looks like you just transpiled typescript in javascript and then tried to serve the files

Comment: well going by your edit, the issue is that your files are named wrong, you shouldnt have the random characters in it

Comment: are you building an angular 6 or angular 7 project?

Comment: @DevanshuKashyap let's start from beginning, are you sure they are build files?

Comment: I'd expect build files to appear in `build` or `dist`, if you find them in peer level with your ts, then they're just transpiled files! Maybe they're just generated by your IDE or by your `tsc` configuration

Comment: In `angular.json` put some value in `baseHref` and `deployUrl` and go to that context root using apache tomcat server. Cause of the error is that, it cannot find the js files which you build.

Comment: @DevanshuKashyap Inside `options`. The full json path is `projects > {Your Application name} > architect > build > options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved by appending **base-href** option to the build command

```
ng build --prod --base-href /myUrl/
```

where **myUrl** is the base Url path.

---

Ref : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build